# Is it possible to link the interactive python window to a running jupyter notebook kernel?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I love the new functionality in VS code to connect to a remote jupter notebook server. It allows me to run jupyter in a docker container and code away...

However when plotting pandas tables, etc. the text output is not always optimal and for quick iteration it would be great to have eg. bokeh interactive plots available.

So I was thinking the following - would it be possible to start a jupyter notebook and after that connect VS Code to the corresponding kernel. Basically the way you can also connect an existing kernel for a running notebook.

the way I can do that now:

1. start jupyter notebook server
2. start new notebook
3. in the notebook execute the following magic command `%connect_info`
4. this returns a json bit and some intstructions - just copy the json
5. in another bash shell I can write this json to a file called my_kernel.json and execute `jupyter console --existing my_kernel.json`

now I have my notebook in my browser and my console connecting to the same kernel. So any variable available in my browser is also available in my console (and vice versa).

Would something like executing step 5 be possible in VSCode to... 
I would love to send code from my editor window to my interactive python console and have access to that same kernel from my notebook...

Comment: Hey Geoffrey. I'm a developer on the VSCode Python Extension team. Do you mind if I ask a clarification question just to make sure that I understand your scenario. You mentioned having to hook this up via the console and getting text only output. If you want richer output you should be able to use the Interactive Window that we create to see rich output from a remote server. Is the reason that you are using the console to connect because you need something like --existing for the Interactive Window remote connection?

Comment: Let me try to elaborate... My end goal is to have both the interactive window in vs code and a notebook in a browser connect to the same kernel (running in a docker container). The reason for this is that the interactive window is great for outputting cell results, but it still misses some interactive features I am used to ( eg bokeh plots, nicely formated dataframes, code completion in the interactive window - eg. With a dataframe find some of the column names). I am now more or less able to get to the result I want by launching a notebook server in my docker container, attaching

Comment: VS code to that container through the docker extension in such a way it runs in my terminal. Run the jupyter console --extend in that terminal and let Ctrl+shift send my selection/current line in my editor to my terminal.. but I would love to have the interactive window option

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was guessing, but I wanted to be sure. We don't currently support this, but I'll open up an issue to track it. It seems to me like a scenario that would be good to support.

Comment: Awesome...... Can I upvote it somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I just posed the link below as an answer since (sadly) the answer is that we don't currently support it. I'm poking around a bit now to see if there is some hack way to connect around this, but I'm not currently turning up anything.

Comment: This is the biggest complaint I have with VSCode currently. It can't replace browsers for accessing kernels for the simple reason that I can't keep a kernel running after I close my laptop. That's the whole point of a remote server.

Comment: Check the solution to the github issue below.. I think it is possible now...

Answer (score 4):

Currently this isn't supported. We supported connecting to a remote server, but on that remote server we start up a new untitled document that we use. We don't currently have a method to hook up to an already running kernel.

I created this issue to track it here if you want to track / upvote:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4644

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do it the other way:

1. Start a kernel with VS code by connecting to a remote Jupyter server, as documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server).
2. Start another Jupyter notebook and connect it to the existing kernel (started by VS code) using [extipy](https://github.com/ebanner/extipy).