# Connect to existing kernel in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, atom-editor

With the recent sunsetting of Atom, I am migrating to VS Code for exploratory analysis of scientific data.

Currently in VS Code, I am able to run my Python files (not Jupyter notebooks) in [cell mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) by starting a local iPython for each .py file. This works fine and reproduces a subset of the functionality I had with Atom/Hydrogen.

However, with Atom/Hydrogen, I could connect multiple .py files to a single kernel. To do this I would start Python in one file. Then I would switch to another file and bring up the Atom command palette and select "Hydrogen: Connect to Existing Kernel". After that both files shared the same kernel, workspace, variables, etc.

I have not been able to reproduce this functionality in VS Code. There is [guidance](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) on how to connect to existing Jupyter kernels using Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code, but the steps there do not work for me when using .py files. There is [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987778/is-it-possible-to-link-the-interactive-python-window-to-a-running-jupyter-notebo) that seems to describe a similar problem but, again, it's notebook-specific.

How can I connect multiple .py files to a single kernel in VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I code two files.

**test1.py**

```
x=1
```

**test2.py**

```
print(x)
```

Obviously, when I run them alone in the interactive window, test2 will make an error. It cannot find the defined x.

However, search **Jupyter: Interactive Windows Mode** in settings and change it to **multiple**.

They can work in the same kernel. Hope this can help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unless I am missing something, this functionality is not as full-featured as the Atom behavior, where one could select which kernel you wanted the file to connect to, instead of sharing one kernel for all files in a window... but this setting does fulfill the original question.